# ELMAH.MVC: How to display custom error page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, elmah.mvc

I am using the latest version of ELMAH.MVC in an ASP.NET MVC4 application.
It is logging errors but, I want to display a custom error page.  So, I 
created an ErrorController and ErrorView (see following).

What I cannot figure out is how to make ELMAH.MVC go to my
custom error page for any uncaught exceptions.  Additionally, I want to show a custom 
title and error message.  I don't have a "customError" in web.config.

I would really appreciate your help with this question...

Thanks,

Mike

```
// ELMAH Configuration
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="ABitOfHelp" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />


// My Error Controller
/// <summary>
/// Logs errors.
/// </summary>
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs JavaScript errors.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogJavaScriptError(string message)
    { 
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new JavaScriptException(message));
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        ViewBag.Title = XXXXX.Shared.Properties.Resources.Title_ErrorInformation;
        return View("Error");
    }
}

// My Error View
```

@   {
    }

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
```

Comment: Wow!  I figured that this must be a common question/issue, but no responses.  I hope that someone will give me a few suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config you need to add the line:

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
```

where mycustompage.htm is the path to either your controller or your page.